# Ruby - Accessing an Array from Inside a Function

Tags: ruby, arrays

Ruby Newb here. I'm trying to write a program that accepts user input, compares it with numbers in an array, and if there's a match, adds it to another number passed to the function. Like so:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

def add(start_num, list)
  print "What number will you add?> "
  number = gets.chomp

  if list.index(number) != nil
    start_num = start_num.to_i
    number = number.to_i
    sum = start_num + number
    puts "Your sum is #{sum}."
  else 
    puts "Not an acceptable number."
  end
end

add(10, numbers)
```

Every time it gets to the point where it compares `list.index(number)` to `nil`, it apparently doesn't pass, and spits out "Not an acceptable answer." So, for some reason, even if the user-input number matches a number from the `numbers` array, apparently the index is still equal to `nil`.

Anybody have a clue how I can make the test pass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just convert the string to number as

```
 number = gets.chomp.to_i
```

In your code, you were searching inside the list the *number*, which is basically *string*. That's the reason your `if` condition always evaluated as *falsy*. BTW,

```
number = gets.to_i
```

Will work too.

Comment: Wow. Yeah, it really was that simple. I seem to keep forgetting that I can use methods on methods on methods, etc. in Ruby, and that 'gets' translates to 'get string.' Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

get.chomp is a string I think try to transform it in a number with gets.chomp.to_i

Answer (score 0):

From one newb to another (I know it can be hard, lol), here are some suggestions to clean up you code a little (I'm sure there are even cleaner versions but here's a start)

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

def add(start_num, list)
  print "What number will you add?> "   #using puts will give the user a new line
  number = gets.chomp    #to_i is best placed here, gets.chomp ALWAYS returns a string

  if list.index(number) != nil   #include? is cleaner and more readable
    start_num = start_num.to_i   #an integer defined in an argument stays an integer, therefor no need for this line
    number = number.to_i     #no need for this line if you define it above
    sum = start_num + number
    puts "Your sum is #{sum}."
  else 
    puts "Not an acceptable number."
  end
end

add(10, numbers)
```

In fact, you can use a [terany](http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/ruby/examples-ruby-ternary-operator-true-false-syntax) to shorten your if statement...so here is your code, the cleaner version:

```
    numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

def add(start_num, list)
  puts "What number will you add?"
  number = gets.chomp.to_i
  sum = start_num + number

  list.include?(number) ? puts("Your sum is #{sum}.") : puts("Not an acceptable number.")

end

add(10, numbers)
```

less code is more;)

Comment: Thanks for the advice... I did use print on line 4 because it accepts user input on the same line (in bash). .include? would have probably been a better option, sure. As for ternary operators: does anybody have a real verdict on the best times to use these? I feel like the traditional if-else makes more sense on the screen in this example.

Comment: hopefully someone chimes in as i would also be interested to know when it is best to use a ternary...when I have tried to put conditional statements within them (nest them) I haven't been able to, and also I have had trouble when trying to put a return statement in them.... but I'm a newb too so perhaps I was doing something wrong that I didn't catch... But if not, then a start to that answer may be that they are best when you don't need to nest or use an elseif nor a return statement? when you have a simple straightforward if/else statement? hopefully more experienced rubyist chime in!